# the @ path alias could not be used in the Vue 3 project

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

When I used vscode to write a Vue3 project ,I ran into an error which is Cannot find module '@/stores' or its corresponding type declaration.

I can't use `@` this path alias

```
import { useUserStore } from '@/stores'
```

`

---

The following is my vite configuration file -- vite.config.js

```js
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    AutoImport({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()]
    }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [ElementPlusResolver()]
    })
  ],
  base: '/',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})
```

I tried to google to solve this problem, but I didn't succeed.

I don't know if it's a problem with the vscode plugin volar

Comment: Is it an editor in the IDE only? That looks like a typescript language service error. Are you using a tsconfig.json or jsconfig.json?

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what the project looks like. There may be various circumstances under which it wouldn't work